# QProcess::terminate() doesn't work with simple Qt app as child process under Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-xp, qprocess

First, my simple Qt app that I will start from a QProcess object:

```
#include <QtGui>

class LOLProcess : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LOLProcess(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~LOLProcess();
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *);
};

LOLProcess::LOLProcess(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
}
LOLProcess::~LOLProcess() {
    qDebug() << "~LOLProcess()";
}
void LOLProcess::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *) {
    qDebug() << "closeEvent()";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    LOLProcess w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Now, the Qt app with the QProcess object:

```
#include <QtGui>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QProcess process;
public slots:
    void close_down();
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    process.start("../../lolprocess-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Release/release/lolprocess.exe");
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, SLOT(close_down()));
}

void MainWindow::close_down() {
    process.terminate();
    while (!process.waitForFinished(500)) {
    qDebug() << process.readAllStandardError();
    qDebug() << process.readAllStandardOutput();
    }
    qDebug() << process.waitForFinished(5000);
    qDebug() << (process.state() == QProcess::Running);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Behavior: terminate() causes the child process's window to vanish (and from the XP taskbar), but the process is still running according to taskman. The `while (!process.waitForFinished(500))` loops forever since the QProcess object never emits finished(). Surprisingly, I get nothing over stdin or stderr from the child process (it prints only the empty string for the `QProcess::readAllStandard...()` calls) which seems odd because the child process's top window closing makes me think closeEvent() was called in the child process.

Terminating the child process with QProcess::kill() works, but I don't want to use it because it doesn't give the child process a chance to clean up before exiting.

Interestingly, this same code works correctly under Qt 4.7.4 and OS X 10.6.x - terminate() causes the child process to exit cleanly, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong under XP. Thanks.

Comment: I think, you should accept close event or call parent class method in your `LOLProcess`

Comment: Lol4t0, thanks for the comment. I tried inserting `event->accept();` in closeEvent(), but the behavior is the same - terminate() doesn't correctly close the child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try now:

```
#include <QtGui>

class LOLProcess : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LOLProcess(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~LOLProcess();
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *);

public slots:
    void lastWindowClosed();
};

LOLProcess::LOLProcess(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
}
LOLProcess::~LOLProcess() {
    qDebug() << "~LOLProcess()";
}
void LOLProcess::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *) {
    qDebug() << "closeEvent()";
}

void LOLProcess::lastWindowClosed (){
    QApplication::quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    LOLProcess w;
    QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()), &w, SLOT(lastWindowClosed()));
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

This should not be necesary. Seems like some really weird quirk/bug in qt - when I have more time I will investigate it further.

Comment: Good workaround, but as you say, it seems to be a bug. Why does QProcess::terminate() work fine on e.g. mspaint.exe but not a simple Qt app? Maybe it needs to be reported.

Comment: When I figure out what is actually wrong with QT I will see if it's worth reporting. For now you will have to live with this workaround as I don't have much time for that. I already figured out, that Quit event is being correctly send to application. Why it is being dismissed during processing remains to be seen...